# not a function and bind of undefined errors in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, jsx

Getting not a function (or) if I bind I am getting bind of undefined error, how should I be binding such functions that pass in a value? What am I missing here..? help needed.

Child Component:

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handler = this.handler.bind(this);
           this.state = {
          isBoolFlag: true,
        }
      }

      onClick(e){
         this.setState({
          isBoolFlag: !this.state.isBoolFlag,
       });
        this.props.handler(!this.state.isBoolFlag); //Error here..

      }

      render() {
        return (
          <div>
                 <a onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

**Parent component:**

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handler = this.handler.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      showModule: false,
    };
  }

 <div>
 {this.state.showModule ? <Child2 /> : <Child1 handler={this.handler} />}
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `this.handler = this.handler.bind(this);` in the Child component. The function `handler` must be a function defined  in the parent.

Also, be careful with:

```
this.setState({
          isBoolFlag: !this.state.isBoolFlag,
       });
this.props.handler(!this.state.isBoolFlag); //Error here..
```

Using this code **you can't rely on `isBoolFlag` being changed** in the state before the `handler` is called **because setState is async**. You should send a callback function as the second argument of [setState](http://thereignn.ghost.io/on-the-async-nature-of-setstate-in-react/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already have that defined in Parent, but I am still getting the error  this.props. handler is not a function(…). And thanks for pointing it out, I have also just realized setState does not reflect immediately.

Comment: No problem :) Could you add to your question the Parent's component code or at least the code of the function?

Comment: I have added Parent's component code also to the question, let me know if you cannot see it .. just updated the question again  http://stackoverflow.com/users/6499571/c%c3%a9sar-landesa

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a callback function in the setState since setState takes some time to mutuate the state and javascript is asynchronous, so `this.state.isBookFlag` is being used with its previous state only.

Use it like

```
this.setState({
          isBoolFlag: !this.state.isBoolFlag,
       }, function(){
      this.props.handler(!this.state.isBoolFlag);
 });
```

Also you only need to bind the handler function in the parent component and not in the child component

Code child component.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

       this.state = {
      isBoolFlag: true,
    }
  }

  onClick(e){
     this.setState({
          isBoolFlag: !this.state.isBoolFlag,
       }, function(){
      if(this.props.handler !== undefined) {
         this.props.handler(!this.state.isBoolFlag);
      }
     });

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
             <a onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Parent:**

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showModule: false,
    };
  }

 <div>
 {this.state.showModule ? <Child2 /> : <Child1 handler={this.handler.bind(this)} />}
            </div>
```

Comment: Yes, I have it in parent component already - but still the same error...http://stackoverflow.com/users/5928186/shubham-khatri

Comment: @monkeyjs you are creating a child component on the basis of a condition and thus in the child component you need to check whether the handler function is defined before calling it. See the updated code

Answer (score 0):

Update:

I missed passing handler to  component just like I did for .